# Suricata - How to use TCP Flags?

Tags: ids, tcp, suricata

I wrote the following rules:

```
alert tcp any any -> 192.168.6.4 any (msg:"SYN"; flags: S;)
alert tcp any any -> 192.168.6.4 any (msg:"FIN"; flags: F;)
```

The SYN rule is matching. The FIN isn't. I can't find a part in their documentation for TCP Flags.

I want to detect packets, where the SYN,FIN,PSH,ACK flags are set. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> alert tcp any any -> 192.168.6.4 any (msg:"FIN"; flags: F;)
> ```

`flags: F` matches packets where the flag is **exactly** FIN.
But if you want to match the end of the connection you usually encounter packets which have both FIN and ACK set - so your rule does not match. To match packets where **at least** FIN is set but other flags might be set to use `flags: F+`.

> I want to detect packets, where the SYN,FIN,PSH,ACK flags are set. How do I do that?

To match **exactly** this combination use `flags: SFPA`

Comment: excerpt from a packet:
"tcp":{"tcp_flags":"1b","tcp_flags_ts":"1b","tcp_flags_tc":"1b","syn":true,"fin":true,"psh":true,"ack":true,"state":"closed"}}

Tried it with:
alert tcp any any -> 192.168.6.4 any (msg:"test"; Flags: SF+;)

But it does not match.

Comment: @flippie: Works for me. I have no idea what you are doing different. But [here](https://filebin.ca/5lW7uQCegy1J/files.tgz) you can find the setup I've used, i.e. the suricata.rules, the pcap file and the eve.json with the alerts. Tested with suricata 6.0.1.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the files. I will check them out to see, what the problem is.